# Apache Flink: Is MapState automatically updated when I modify a stored object?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it necessary to use `MapState.put()` to manually update the state or whether is the state automatically updated when I modify an object?

```
private transient MapState<String, Word> words;
.......
Word w = words.get(word);             
if (w == null) {
  w = new Word(word);
  //words.put(word, w);  //A
}              
if (....) {
  w.countBad(1);   // countXXX modifies a the private variable in a Word object 
} else {
  w.countGood(1);
}    
//words.put(word, w);   //B
```

**Q**: If I use the A method, will the next count calculation automatically update the corresponding `Mapstate` state? Or do I need to use the B method to manually update the state after the calculation is complete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an API point of view, you always need to manually update the state.

However, the actual behavior depends on the state backend. If the application uses the `InMemoryStateBackend` or the `FsStateBackend`, all local state is stored on the JVM heap of the worker process, i.e., the state backend just holds a reference to the object. Hence, the state is directly modified when you modify the object.

If you use the `RocksDBStateBackend` all state accesses are de/serialized and read from / written to RocksDB. In this case modifying the object does not have an effect on the state.

I recommend to always explicitly update the state because this will ensure that you can switch the state backend without adjusting the logic of your application.

Comment: And because updating a state is not cost-less, you should update it a single time.
So, B is enough, remove A.