# Flink MapStateDescriptor update List value

Tags: apache-flink

I use a `MapStateDescriptor` for my stateful computation. Some code here

`final val myMap = new MapStateDescriptor[String, List[String]]("myMap", classOf[String], classOf[List[String]])`

During my computation i want to update my map by adding new elements to the `List[String]`.

Is it possible?

**Update #1**

have written following def to manage my map

```
def updateTagsMapState(mapKey: String, tagId: String, mapToUpdate: MapState[String, List[String]]): Unit = {
  if (mapToUpdate.contains(mapKey)) {
    val mapValues: List[String] = mapToUpdate.get(mapKey)
    val updatedMapValues: List[String] = tagId :: mapValues
    mapToUpdate.put(mapKey, updatedMapValues)
  } else {
    mapToUpdate.put(mapKey,List(tagId))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is. Depending on whether this is Scala `List` or Java that You will be using there you can do smth like that to actually create the state from descriptor:

```
lazy val stateMap = getRuntimeContext.getMapState(myMap)
```

Then You can simply do:

```
val list = stateMap.get("someKey")
stateMap.put("someKey", list +: "SomeVal")
```

Note that if You would work with mutable data structure, You wouldn't necessarily need to call `put` again, since the update of the data structure would also update the state. But this approach does not work in case of RocksDB state, since the state is only updated after You call `put` in this case, so it is always advised to update the state itself instead of just underlying object.

Comment: thanks. posted update with my function to manage my map. looks ok.
can You pls elaborate a bit more about issue when using RocksDB ?

Comment: You can find the response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257240/apache-flink-is-mapstate-automatically-updated-when-i-modify-a-stored-object

Comment: thanks!
my stateful computation i do sits inside `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` ( i connect bcast stream with keyed data stream)
inside a class i have defined few `MapStateDescriptor` (not broadcast) and manage the state inside `processBroadcastElement` and `processElement` defs.
do i understand correctly - state i have inside my `MapStateDescriptor` are different per parallelism i have? mean state not shared between different operator instances?